# Limit of $g(t)\int_0^t f(u)du$

Tags: integration

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to show this fact

"If $g$ is a positive continuous decreasing function on $[0,1]$ such that $g(1)=0$, then for any positive $f$ such that $\int_0^1 f(u)g(u)\text{d}u < + \infty$ then $\lim_{t \nearrow 1} g(t)\int_0^t f(u) \text{d}u=0$ "

I've tried to show that $\int_0^1 f(u)\text{d}u<+\infty$ with inequalities but it wasn't successful.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thank you very much.